# Zepplin: truncated output with self defined sql interpreter

Tags: sql, jdbc, apache-zeppelin

I use Zeppelin 0.7.2 and created for testing purposes an own "interpreter" for directly querying a sql database using jdbc. If I use the sql query `select col from table` in zeppelin, check the scatter plot view or download the data as csv file from the inbuilt view I get only about 7.800 rows. The interpreter is configured with `common.max_count=1000000000` and `zeppelin.interpreter.output.limit=102400`

If I use the same query with a sql client I get about 22.000 row.

So I wonder why there is a difference.

Comment: Hi, could you check `ZEPPELIN_WEBSOCKET_MAX_TEXT_MESSAGE_SIZE` as well? which is described in https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.2/install/configuration.html

Comment: No, it is not a solution. I set it to a very high number and restarted the zeppelin-daemon but it still only shows the less 7.800 rows.

Comment: What's the average size of a row? and please attach your error logs. If it's truncated there should be log about it.

Comment: I have have two columns with doubles. If I download the csv file, it size is 101 kb that seems to be the `zeppelin.interpreter.output.limit` of this interpreter. I raised it by a factor of ~10 to `112400`, reloaded the interpreter and also restarted zeppelin but I still get the 101 kb csv file. And now I also see the log line below the image which says "Output exceeds 102400. Truncated." If I open the interpreter configuration `zeppelin.interpreter.output.limit` is back to the lower value. Strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by modify the config file : conf/zeppelin-site.xml

raise the size of :

> zeppelin.interpreter.output.limit
>
> zeppelin.websocket.max.text.message.size

[related link](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.2/install/configuration.html)

Comment: Dont add the following properties. It will make your zeppelin server down and you will need to re-install the server. Be careful.

I have tried the same thing twice and resulted in to installing the zeppelin again

Answer (score 0):

You get only 7800 / 22000 rows back because both the row count and the memory limit configuration is respected. In your case the memory limit is probably the culprit.

I wouldn't suggest changing the default configuration of the Zeppelin instance. Instead you can add the custom configuration in the first cell of your Zeppelin notebook like so:

```
%spark.conf
zeppelin.interpreter.output.limit=10000000
zeppelin.spark.maxResult=5000
```

This sets the limits to 5000 rows and 10MB in size. [Docs link](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/interpreter/spark.html) for Spark interpreter configuration.

Tested on Zeppelin Version 0.10.1